# Transfering User Names from One Forum to Another?

Tags: data-transfer, vbulletin

How do I transfer the users of a vBulletin forum to a new installation of IceBB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, they both have a database back-end of some sort, right? SQL dump, followed by patching stuff up in your favorite scripting language, followed by SQL load, seems do-able.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called [ImpEx](http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/showthread.php?p=982086) for vBulletin to do exactly this. It imports and exports users and data. Doing the SQL yourself can be error prone and difficult compared to using ImpEx.